# cutting text for parts using grep and patterns

Tags: r, regex, datetime

I have very dirty txt file (.json) i one column. I want to cut this file for n parts. The patterns which should be used to cut this is character string for example "2018-02-19 10:49:50 " (date and time are different of course). I should use grep?

I have data like this:

```
      text
1    2018-02-19 10:49:50 fgdfhdsgfhdsgfh 2018-02-19 10:49:50 abd abd adjskfjs 
     2018-02-19 10:51:21 jfhdsjfdsf
```

And my desired output is:

```
      textA                 textB             textC
1    fgdfhdsgfhdsgfh   abd abd adjskfjs     jfhdsjfdsf
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can split the strings based on the pattern indicating the date and time, and then trim the white space.

```
text <- "2018-02-19 10:49:50 fgdfhdsgfhdsgfh 2018-02-19 10:49:50 abd abd adjskfjs 2018-02-19 10:51:21 jfhdsjfdsf"

text2 <- trimws(strsplit(text, split = "\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}")[[1]][-1])

text2
# [1] "fgdfhdsgfhdsgfh"  "abd abd adjskfjs" "jfhdsjfdsf"
```

**Update**

If we are working on a column from a data frame and we want the output to be in separated columns, we can use the `str_split` function from the [stringr](/questions/tagged/stringr) package. Notice that in the following example, I duplicated the original text to form a data frame with one column and two rows.

```
library(stringr)
text <- "2018-02-19 10:49:50 fgdfhdsgfhdsgfh 2018-02-19 10:49:50 abd abd adjskfjs 2018-02-19 10:51:21 jfhdsjfdsf"
text_df <- data.frame(text = rep(text, 2), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
m1 <- str_split(text_df$text, pattern = "\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}", simplify = TRUE)
m2 <- m1[, 2:ncol(m1)]
m3 <- apply(m2, 2, trimws)
m3
#      [,1]              [,2]               [,3]        
# [1,] "fgdfhdsgfhdsgfh" "abd abd adjskfjs" "jfhdsjfdsf"
# [2,] "fgdfhdsgfhdsgfh" "abd abd adjskfjs" "jfhdsjfdsf"
```

Comment: I have
Error in strsplit(text, split = "\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}") : 
  non-character argument

Comment: Can you run my example?

Comment: If my example works, then your next step is figuring out what is the difference between my example and your real-world dataset.

Comment: @littlegirl Please see my update. Since you did not provide a reproducible example of your data, I can only guess what could be your data format. Next time, please use `dput` to share your dataset.

Comment: In real I have json file, which I try to upload to R like text file